# No __init__.py, but still considered a package?

Tags: package, python-3.4, python-import

### `A foobar package`

> - #### foobar
>
>   - __init__.py
>   - foo.py
>   - #### bar
>
>     - bar.py

---

### `Inside the __init__.py`

```
from . import foo
from . import bar
```

---

Even though `bar` is not a package or a sub-package, it is still imported as a module *(lolwut)*. I checked the import type by doing `print(type(bar))` inside the `__init__.py` and it printed `<class 'module'>`... that's it. What's going on here? It is a module object, so I did `print(dir(bar))` and the output was `['__doc__', '__loader__', '__name__', '__package__', '__path__', '__spec__']`. Now, what's even more confusing to me is the `__path__` variable in this. Isn't that a package-only thing?

Is this what's known as a namespace-package? I am thinking that it isn't, nevertheless I tried one more thing inside that `__init__.py` file - added a line `import bar.bar`. It ended in an `ImportError`. So, to sum up my question, what is this module useful for? Why did Python import this in the first place?

[There's an amazing tutorial on this entire topic by David Beazley](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=0oTh1CXRaQ0). I have watched the whole thing a while ago, but I guess I should watch it again to recollect everything.

Answer (score 0):

From [the docs](https://docs.python.org/3.4/tutorial/modules.html)

> A **module is a file containing Python definitions and statements**. The file name is the module name with the suffix .py appended. Within a module, the module’s name (as a string) is available as the value of the global variable `__name__`.
>
> ...
>
> Packages are a way of structuring Python’s module namespace by using “dotted module names”. For example, the module name A.B designates a submodule named B in a package named A.
>
> ...
>
> Packages support one more special attribute, `__path__`. This is initialized to be a list containing the name of the directory holding the package’s `__init__.py` before the code in that file is executed. This variable can be modified; doing so affects future searches for modules and subpackages contained in the package.
>
> While this feature is not often needed, **it can be used to extend the set of modules found in a package**.

So yes, the `__path__` variable is applied to the modules inside a package as well and those modules are treated as 'submodules of a package'

*Edit*
In Python 2.x, that package with the `from . import bar` would return an `ImportError` at that line. On Python 3.x the `modulefoobar.foo` has a type of `<module 'foobar.foo' from '../py/foobar/foo.py'>` and the `foobar.bar` of `<module 'foobar.bar' (namespace)>`.

Apparently, it appeared [here](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0420/#specification)

> Regular packages will continue to have an init.py and will reside in a single directory. Namespace packages cannot contain an init.py

Comment: Thank you for the answer. _"This is initialized to be a list containing the name of the directory holding the package’s `__init__.py`"_ in my example above, there was no `__init__` in the bar folder, yet it was treated as a package and something was imported. I must confess that this is getting more and more confusing to me.

Comment: In Python 2.x, that package with the `from . import bar` would return an `ImportError` at that line. On Python 3.x the module`foobar.foo` has a type of `<module 'foobar.foo' from '../py/foobar/foo.py'>`and the `foobar.bar` of `<module 'foobar.bar' (namespace)>`. Apparently, it appeared [here](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0420/#specification)

>Regular packages will continue to have an __init__.py and will reside in a single directory.

Namespace packages cannot contain an __init__.py

Comment: Please update your answer with that last comment, as it is what actually answers the OP's question.